# How do I move a Python 3.6 installation a different directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed Python `3.6.2`  Windows in

`c:\users\username\AppData\Local\programs\Python\Python36`

(because that is the (totally stupid) default.

I have manually moved that into `c:\`

But the update to Python `3.6.3` still installs to the original target.

How do I change this (without uninstalling (which would also uninstall all packages))?

Comment: Reverse your manul steps, uninstall and reinstall. In the end that is how Windows rolls.

Comment: I'm having the same issue because the Windows 10 App Store installed Python 3.8 in my user folder.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure this will be the best answer though the simplest thing to do if you are stuck you could try this.

You could move you installation back to its original location, then update it.
Then once complete move it to where you want.

---

Alternatively, there is a registry value that shows Python installation path. I would check to see if this reflects your new path, if not then updating it may allow your update to work. The location of the registry on my machine is:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.6\InstallPath
```

Comment: FYI: If you have a 32-bit version of Python running on a 64-bit operating system, the registry path is either `HKCU\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Python\PythonCore\3.6-32\InstallPath` or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Python\PythonCore\3.6-32\InstallPath` depending on whether you installed for the current user or all users respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much. I suspect chocolatey or something else modified this registry setting to C:\Python39 and it was messing up py launcher on windows 10. Putting it back to the original fixed my problem (the opposite of the OP)

Comment: For me, I had to change registry keys there : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\<version>`

Answer (score 5):

If you installed Python for all users, the registry path (64bit Python on 64bit OS) would be:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Idle
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\InstallPath
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\PythonPath
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\3.8\Help\Main Python
  Documentation
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\editwithidle\shell\edit38\command
- HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.NoConFile\Shell\editwithidle\shell\edit38\command

Comment: I moved the installed folder manually, then changed my system PATH to point there, then updated all these registries, restart, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the problem is that you didn't change the environment PATH in your windows settings. If you modify the path to c:\Python36 folder everything should be back to norm.

Here are instructions how to do this [Modify environment PATH on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Comment: Python 3.6 is not in my path. (Wouldn't help, because I got numerous other versions (2.7, 3.3, 3.5, 32 bit, 64 bit) on the same system). That's why I needed a simple path in the first place.

Comment: @RuedigerJungbeck If your primary concern is packages which will be uninstalled. You can do `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and later recover it with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Pip freeze only works for packages installed from PyPI, but not for packages installed from other sources (like local (e.g. numpy with MKL) or github). Why can't i simply change the install location (presumably in the registry). I am able to find the keys for 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 3.5 and but not for 3.6,

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar problem. For some reason I wanted to change the PC admin but my Python was installed on the old user directory.
All updates and repairs I had to do on the same directory.

Then I deleted the python path from registry (Since I wanted to have fresh install later):
**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python**
and then reinstalled python.

PS: While installing on your home PC its better to install across users. My python is installed at below location:
**C:\Program Files\Python37**

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to uninstall and reinstall. On the reinstall select "Customize installation".

At the third prompt check "Install Python for all users". Below it will change the path. You can all just type in the path you want to use too.

[Here's an image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M03sE.png)